# Golang использование exe файла с другой папки

Tags: golang

Скомпилировал простое web приложение. Перенес exe файл в другую папку(на уровень выше) запустил, захожу на url, пишет ошибки:

```
    net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0820a6080, 0x2b900
58, 0xc0820e65b0, 0xc0820e9340)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x1a5
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0820a6d00)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf35
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x455
2016/06/03 14:18:31 http: panic serving [::1]:64108: r
untime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer de
reference
goroutine 22 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0820fb680)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc8
panic(0x7a1de0, 0xc082006080)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4f7
main.handler(0x2b90058, 0xc082108820, 0xc082126a80)
        C:/GoSource/src/github.com/bsbak/jck/jck.go:14
 +0x17a
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x8cc878, 0x2b90058, 0x
c082108820, 0xc082126a80)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x41
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc082050a20, 0x2b90058
, 0xc082108820, 0xc082126a80)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x184
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0820a6080, 0x2b900
58, 0xc082108820, 0xc082126a80)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x1a5
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0820fb680)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf35
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x455
```

Сам файл:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("tpl/index.html", "tpl/header.html", "tpl/footer.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Name())
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

}

Если exe файла не переносить в другую папку, то работает нормально. Что не так подскажите?

Comment: А как же "подшитые" файлы? "tpl/index.html", "tpl/header.html", "tpl/footer.html" вы их тоже перенесли? Может на них и ругается?

Comment: @nick_n_a точно, не знал... думал все вшивает в exe файл...

Comment: Да тебе после `fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error())` `return` вставить и паника пропадёт. Но ошибка останется.

Answer (score 1):

Не хватает репы для коммента. Если хотите "вшить" свои шаблоны, то используйте https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata

Comment: Да ладно вам. Очень даже годится как ответ, если пояснить суть проблемы (которую уже изложили в комментариях).

Answer (score 0):

`t, err := template.ParseFiles("tpl/index.html", "tpl/header.html", "tpl/footer.html")`

Здесь файлы берутся по относительному пути, поэтому если запустить приложение из другой папки, то .html не найдутся. Вам необходимо переносить папку tpl вместе с Вашим .exe файлом